# How to transfer values of three select option via AJAX to PHP?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 select with values that are pulled from the database in option value. I can transfer 2 input to the database, but the value from the option value is not transfer. Here are my options that I tried and they don't work:

```
            $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                const   input1 = $('#input1').val(),
                        input2 = $('#input2').val();
                let     selest1 = $("#selest1").on('change', () => $("#selest1 option:selected").val()),
                        selest2 = $("#selest2").on('change', () => $("#selest2 option:selected").val()),
                        selest3 = $("#selest3").on('change', () => $("#selest3 option:selected").val());

                if(input1 != '' && input2 != ''){
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"php.php",
                        method:'POST',
                        data: new FormData(this),
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                            
                        success: function(data){},
                        error:function(data){}
                    });
                }
            });
```

```
            $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                const   input1 = $('#input1').val(),
                        input2 = $('#input2').val();

                $("selest").on('change', (){
                        let     selest1 = $("#selest1 option:selected").val(),
                                selest2 = $("#selest2 option:selected").val(),
                                selest3 = $("#selest3 option:selected").val();

                        if(input1 != '' && input2 != ''){
                    
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"php.php",
                                method:'POST',
                                data: new FormData(this),
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                            
                                success: function(data){},
                                error:function(data){}
                            });
                        }
                 })
            });
```

Tell me where I'm wrong, please.

Comment: You're never using any of the `selestX` variables in the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't bind event handlers inside other event handlers.

Comment: Ok, and how can I fix this, because I myself cannot think of it ?

Comment: FYI to get the value of a select you can just write `$("#selest1").val()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare another event handler inside the submit handler.

If the selects aren't in `#form`, you need to append their values to the `FormData` object.

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const input1 = $('#input1').val(),
    input2 = $('#input2').val();

  if (input1 != '' && input2 != '') {
    let selest1 = $("#selest1").val(),
      selest2 = $("#selest2").val(),
      selest3 = $("#selest3").val(),
      fd = new FormData(this);

    fd.append('selest1', selest1);
    fd.append('selest2', selest2);
    fd.append('selest3', select3);

    $.ajax({
      url: "php.php",
      method: 'POST',
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(data) {},
      error: function(data) {}
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I need to pass 3 more values from select option:selected, and I do not understand how to do this. And you did not take them into account. Then only input will be sent to the server. It is not right. I need to pass 5 values: 2 input and 3 select option:selected.

Comment: They're not in the form?

Comment: In the form. You want to explain to me that I have to catch the values in the php file as $_POST["something"] ?

Comment: If they're in the form, `new FormData(this)` should include their values. And PHP will get them in `$_POST['something']`, where it's `<select name="something" id="selest1">`

Comment: `$("#selest1").val()` - so I tried it too, but it didn't work.

Comment: Add the HTML to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I found my stupid mistake, I just didn’t indicate `<select name="something">`

Comment: or you could just serialize the whole form and pass it ? var formData =  $( "#form ).serialize(); then pass that as your data in your ajax request ... data: formData,

Comment: @futureweb Unless there are file inputs in the form.